# complete residue system modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $p$ is odd prime and

$\{a_1,...,a_p\},\{b_1,...,b_p\}$ are  complete residue system modulo $p$

how to prove $\{a_1b_1,...,a_pb_p\}$  is not complete residue system modulo $p$.

[complete residue system modulo $p$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Reduced_residue_systems)

Comment: Assume $a_1=b_1=0$. Consider the product of $a_2b_2,a_3b_3,\ldots$, using wilson theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, notice that each system has an element divisible by $p$ and if the two elements do not have the same index, then the product system has two elements divisible by $p$. Hence, not a complete system in this case. Now suppose $a_p$ and $b_p$ are both the elements divisible by $p$.

Consider the product of the remaining terms. Since the non-zero residues form a cyclic group of even order, there is exactly one element of order 2. Thus, the product of all residues in a system will be congruent to $-1$.

But then, in the product system, $\{a_ib_i\}$ the product of all the terms will be $(-1)^2 = 1$; hence not a complete residue system.