# How to prove that a product of two complete residue system is not a complete residue system?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, products

*Claim*. Let $n$ be a natural number and $A=\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,n-1\}$ be a complete set of residues modulo $n$. Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $A$. Show that the set $C=\{\sigma(i)i:i\in A\}$ is *not* a complete set of residues modulo $n$.

I can prove Claim for a prime number $n$. Indeed, suppose that $n>2$ and $C=\{\sigma(i)i:i\in A\}$ is a complete set of residues modulo $n$. Since $C$ has $n$ different elements, $\sigma(0)=0$. Then

$$\prod_{c\in C\setminus\{0\}}c =1\cdot 2\cdots (n-1)\equiv (n-1)!  \equiv –1 \pmod n,$$

by [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). From the other side,

$$\prod_{c\in C\setminus\{0\}}c =\left(\prod_{a\in A\setminus\{0\}}a\right)^2\equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod n,$$

a contradiction!

But, unfortunately, I cannot prove the claim when $n$ is not a prime.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381268/complete-residue-system-modulo-p

Comment: Hello,your links have no $n$ is not prime case

Comment: Hint/strategy: first show that if it were possible, then the product $\sigma(i)i$ would have to have the same gcd with $n$ as $\sigma(i)$ and $i$ do. (If it got any higher, then some gcd would occur too many times.) Then if $n=pm$ for a prime $p$ and $m>1$, the subset $\{m,2m,\dots,(p-1)m\}$ must be multiplied by a permutation of itself, and the proof you have for the prime case will work again.

Comment: @math110 I corrected your question. Check if all is correct.